# Batch Job's Test code coverage is below 50%

Tags: apex

I have a simple Batch job written shown below:

```
global class LPP_UpdateReasonsBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject>
{   
    global final String query;

    global LPP_UpdateReasonsBatch(String q){
        query = q;        
    }
 
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){        
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);        
    }
        
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope)
    {           
        Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
        for (sObject o : scope)
        {
            Opportunity opp = (Opportunity) o;
            oppIds.add(opp.Id);
        }
        
        OpportunityCustomClass.updateReasons(oppIds);
    }
    
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC)
    {
        //System.debug('Finished Updating Reasons on Opportunities');
    }        
}
```

I wrote the test class for this based on trailheads and examples and it is passing however I only have less than 50% coverage. Basically, nothing in the execute method of the batch is covered and I am not sure why. The test class is below:

```
    @IsTest
    public class LPP_UpdateReasonsBatchTest {
        @testSetup
        static void Testsetup(){
            
                Account testAccount = new Account(Name='Minnesota' , 'MN', 'Hennepin', 'Minneapolis', '55404');
                insert testAccount;
                
                Opportunity testOpportunity =  new Opportunity( testAccount.id , 'Fall' , '2017', 'Confirmed' , false );
                testOpportunity.Year__c = '2017';
                insert testOpportunity;
                
            }
        }
        
        @isTest
        public static void testJob(){
            Test.startTest();
            
            String query = 'SELECT Id from Opportunity where Year__c = \'2017\' and Season__c = \'Fall\'';
            LPP_UpdateReasonsBatch reasonkBatch = new LPP_UpdateReasonsBatch(query);
            Id BatchProcessId = Database.executeBatch(reasonBatch);
            Test.stopTest();
        }
    }
```

Can someone please help? I can provide more code if needed
thank you

Comment: Not sure why is the coverage. Possible you have other processes that change the data. You can try and query the opportunity/account in test after startTest and print their values. Just 1 other comment- it 's seems you created class name Opportunity the one that you used in the test TestSetup. It is usually should be avoided, because when you will reference Opportunity in the code, the compiler might confused between your class and the standard Opportunity object

Answer (score 0):

You aren't inserting any sObjects in your `@testSetup` method. You need to perform an `insert` DML on both the Account and the Opportunity.

Your batch class's `execute()` method is not being called because your query returns no records. If you insert your records, it should execute as expected, provided that (and this does appear to be the case) your test data matches the query.

You should also be writing an assertion at the end of your class to validate that the changes you expect to be performed are performed.

Comment: I apologize @David Reed. I did have insert statements for both I just forgot to copy it. so it is not working with insert statements.

Comment: Please do edit your post to provide complete, reproducible code illustrating the issue.

Comment: I added the insert statments in he code. Did you want to know the code when I call the other class? OpportunityCustomClass.updateReasons(oppIds); inside the execute method?